# Angular5 and TS2307 cannot find moudle in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015

i am trying to integrate the Angular in Visual Studio 2015 update 3. and the the following error 
TS2307 cannot find module '../node_modules/@angular/core' which was show in following image. Can anyone figure out i am doing wrong here.
[image]

My Typescript setting for Visual Studio 2015 update 3 is as follows

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
<TypeScriptTarget>ES6</TypeScriptTarget>
<TypeScriptJSXEmit>None</TypeScriptJSXEmit>
<TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
<TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
<TypeScriptModuleKind />
<TypeScriptRemoveComments>False</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
<TypeScriptOutFile />
<TypeScriptOutDir />
<TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>False</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
<TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>true</TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>
<TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>True</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
<TypeScriptSourceMap>True</TypeScriptSourceMap>
<TypeScriptMapRoot />
<TypeScriptSourceRoot />
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to us e`../node_modules` part. Just try `@angular/platform-browser-dynamic` like

```
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Changed according to your suggestion. Still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Change your `import` with this :

```
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
```

> None of the npm packages requires to import from `../node_modules` , you
>   can directly use the package name
>
> You need to use the relative path only for angular `component` /
>   `directive` / `modules` or files which are no inside node_modules folder
>
> you are also using `'../node_modules/@angular/core'` change that to
>   `'@angular/core'`

Remove '../node_modules/' from every where.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Changed according to your suggestion. Still getting same error

Comment: @himadri, you are also using ''../node_modules/@angular/core'' change that to '@angular/core'

Comment: changed. ..../node_modules/@angular/core-->@angular/core and Others also. But Same Error. "Could not find module @angular/core"

Comment: Is it possible to share the project?

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot for your help and interest. please download the project from following URL. you need visual studio 2015 update 3 to run the project https://www.dropbox.com/s/yzttyifc7kpnudv/Angular5_DotNet_MVC_2.rar?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just `npm install`? 
or delete nodes folder and try `npm install`.
safed my problems with this error.